# Error Populating Users

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, yeoman

For some reason, whenever I create a new user in the database, it tries to add another user before and then errors out.

I am using Yeoman's generator angular-fullstack to create an api for my application. In this last week, I started noticing that when my database was populating, it did not display "finished populating users", signifying that it is not successfully adding users in my seed.js file. Here is my seed.js file.

**Seed.js**

```
'use strict';

var Thing = require('../api/thing/thing.model');
var User = require('../api/user/user.model');
var Item = require('../api/item/item.model');
var Calendar = require('../api/calendar/calendar.model');

Thing.find({}).remove(function() {});

User.find({}).remove(function() {
  User.create({
    provider: 'local',
    role: 'student',
    name: 'Student',
    email: 'student@test.com',
    password: 'test',
    pin: '0807'
  }, {
    provider: 'local',
    role: 'teacher',
    name: 'Teacher',
    email: 'teacher@test.com',
    password: 'test',
    pin: '0807'
  }, {
      provider: 'local',
      role: 'admin',
      name: 'Admin',
      email: 'admin@admin.com',
      password: 'admin',
      pin: '0807'
  }, function() {
    console.log('finished populating users');
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});

Calendar.find({}).remove(function() {});
console.log("Removed Calendars");

Item.find({}).remove(function () {
  Item.create({
      calendarId: "dd7sfasd8f8sd",
      title: "title",
      description: "description",
      date: new Date(),
      checklists: [],
      attachments: [],
      status: "Not Completed",
      edit: false,
      verification: "test", //This will not be here in the long run
      verify: false
    }, {
      calendarId: "323k3k2l23lk4j4",
      title: "other",
      description: "description",
      date: new Date(),
      checklists: [],
      attachments: [],
      status: "Completed",
      edit: false,
      verification: "test", //This will not be here in the long run
      verify: false
    }, {
      calendarId: "323k3k2l23lk4j4",
      title: "title",
      description: "description",
      date: new Date(),
      checklists: [],
      attachments: [],
      status: "Verified",
      edit: false,
      verification: "test", //This will not be here in the long run
      verify: false
    }, {
      calendarId: "323k3k2l23lk4j4",
      title: "test",
      description: "description",
      date: new Date(),
      checklists: [],
      attachments: [],
      status: "Not Completed",
      edit: false,
      verification: "test", //This will not be here in the long run
      verify: false

    }, function() {
      console.log('finished populating items');
    }
  );

});
```

When I added the function when an error occurred, it displayed this:

```
Express server listening on 9000, in development mode
Done waiting!

Running "open:server" (open) task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
{ _id: 5704a4d8b414a48822cd30a6, students: [], role: 'teacher' }
[Error: Invalid or no password]
finished populating items
```

As you might notice, the object displaying as the user to add is not the users in my seed.js file. To save time in looking through my entire model, here is the method where I am printing that user being created and where this error is occuring:

```
UserSchema
      .pre('save', function(next) {
        if (!this.isNew) return next();
        console.log(this);
        if (!validatePresenceOf(this.hashedPassword) && authTypes.indexOf(this.provider) === -1) {
          next(new Error('Invalid or no password'));
        if (!validatePresenceOf(this.hashedPin))
          next(new Error('Invalid pin'));
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
```

However, for more information into this error, I have the whole file shown below:

**user.model.js**

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var crypto = require('crypto');
var authTypes = ['github', 'twitter', 'facebook', 'google'];

var Student = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  age: Number
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'teacher'
  },
  teachersEmail: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  students: [Student],
  status: String,
  hashedPassword: String,
  hashedPin: String,
  hasPassword: Boolean,
  provider: String,
  salt: String,
  pinSalt: String,
  facebook: {},
  twitter: {},
  google: {},
  github: {}
});

/**
 * Virtuals
 */
UserSchema
  .virtual('password')
  .set(function(password) {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = this.makeSalt();
    this.hashedPassword = this.encryptPassword(password);
  })
  .get(function() {
    return this._password;
  });

UserSchema
  .virtual('pin')
  .set(function(pin) {
    this._pin = pin;
    this.pinSalt = this.makeSalt();
    this.hashedPin = this.encryptPin(pin);
  })
  .get(function() {
    return this._pin;
  });

// Public profile information
UserSchema
  .virtual('profile')
  .get(function() {
    return {
      'name': this.name,
      'role': this.role
    };
  });

// Non-sensitive info we'll be putting in the token
UserSchema
  .virtual('token')
  .get(function() {
    return {
      '_id': this._id,
      'role': this.role
    };
  });

/**
 * Validations
 */

// Validate empty email
UserSchema
  .path('email')
  .validate(function(email) {
    if (authTypes.indexOf(this.provider) !== -1) return true;
    return email.length;
  }, 'Email cannot be blank');

// Validate empty password
UserSchema
  .path('hashedPassword')
  .validate(function(hashedPassword) {
    if (authTypes.indexOf(this.provider) !== -1) return true;
    return hashedPassword.length;
  }, 'Password cannot be blank');

// Validate empty pin
UserSchema
  .path('hashedPin')
  .validate(function(hashedPin) {
    return hashedPin.length;
  }, 'PIN cannot be blank');

// Validate empty pin
UserSchema
  .path('hashedPin')
  .validate(function(hashedPin) {
    return hashedPin.length == 4;
  }, 'PIN must be 4 characters in length');

// Validate email is not taken
UserSchema
  .path('email')
  .validate(function(value, respond) {
    var self = this;
    this.constructor.findOne({email: value}, function(err, user) {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(user) {
        if(self.id === user.id) return respond(true);
        return respond(false);
      }
      respond(true);
    });
}, 'The specified email address is already in use.');

var validatePresenceOf = function(value) {
  return value && value.length;
};

/**
 * Pre-save hook
 */
UserSchema
  .pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!this.isNew) return next();
    console.log(this);
    if (!validatePresenceOf(this.hashedPassword) && authTypes.indexOf(this.provider) === -1) {
      next(new Error('Invalid or no password'));
    if (!validatePresenceOf(this.hashedPin))
      next(new Error('Invalid pin'));
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
/**
 * Methods
 */
UserSchema.methods = {
  /**
   * Authenticate - check if the passwords are the same
   *
   * @param {String} plainText
   * @return {Boolean}
   * @api public
   */
  authenticate: function(plainText) {
    if (this.hashedPassword) {
      return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashedPassword;
    } else {
      return !!(this.google || this.facebook);
    }
  },

  verify: function(plainText) {
    return this.encryptPin(plainText) === this.hashedPin;
  },

  /**
   * Make salt
   *
   * @return {String}
   * @api public
   */
  makeSalt: function() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
  },

  /**
   * Encrypt password
   *
   * @param {String} password
   * @return {String}
   * @api public
   */
  encryptPassword: function(password) {
    if (!password || !this.salt) return '';
    var salt = new Buffer(this.salt, 'base64');
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
  },

  encryptPin: function(pin) {
    if (!pin || !this.pinSalt) return '';
    var pinSalt = new Buffer(this.pinSalt, 'base64');
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(pin, pinSalt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
  }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Finally, I decided to separately add users in my seed.js file to see what happens, like so...

```
User.find({}).remove(function() {
  User.create({
    provider: 'local',
    role: 'student',
    name: 'Student',
    email: 'student@test.com',
    password: 'test',
    pin: '0807'
  }, function() {
    console.log('Added user');
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  User.create({
    provider: 'local',
    role: 'teacher',
    name: 'Teacher',
    email: 'teacher@test.com',
    password: 'test',
    pin: '0807'
  }, function() {
    console.log('Added user');
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
  User.create({
      provider: 'local',
      role: 'admin',
      name: 'Admin',
      email: 'admin@admin.com',
      password: 'admin',
      pin: '0807'
  }, function() {
    console.log('Added user');
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Here is what the terminal displayed:

```
Running "watch" task
Completed in 2.258s at Wed Apr 06 2016 00:08:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) - Waiting...
{ _id: 5704a7e2d85623902a78e1fc, students: [], role: 'teacher' }
[Error: Invalid or no password]
{ _id: 5704a7e2d85623902a78e1fe, students: [], role: 'teacher' }
[Error: Invalid or no password]
{ _id: 5704a7e2d85623902a78e200, students: [], role: 'teacher' }
[Error: Invalid or no password]
finished populating items
```

The main problem here, is that it is adding a user that I did not add. (I added three. the first one is named "Student". The terminal is showing a user with no name, no email, nothing. Keep in mind that when I add users through my signup screen, this does not happen. The user is added fine...

What could be causing this?

Comment: I can't understand the problem, you didn't give the hashedPassword so it returns the error you set.

Comment: Actually, if you go to the UserSchema, when you save the password, it creates the hashedPassword as long as I have a password. I have that shown in the user.model.js. Also, I just added a few sentences before asking "What could be causing this?" to explain the problem.

Comment: Notice that the user it is adding is all default data (its like it is adding null data) - { _id: 5704a4d8b414a48822cd30a6, students: [], role: 'teacher' }. _id is generated automatically, default role is teacher, default for array is an empty array.

Comment: Where is the function to create the hashedPassword? I don't think you are getting/returning it.

Comment: Where is says UserSchema.virtual('password').set(function(password) in the second block of code (the file name bolded is user.model.js. To prove that this is not the problem, if I create a user through my signup screen with just a name, password and username, it returns a hashedPassword, so that is not the problem.